# Phaser 3 image overlapping

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

```
this.modes =  ['Background', 'Text'];
this.currentMode = this.modes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.modes.length)];

if (this.currentMode == 'Text' ) {
        this.imageShape = 'textImage'
} else {
        this.imageShape = 'bgImage';
}
let images = this.add.image(385, 460, this.imageShape)
```

We have two images: the first one, `'textImage'`, displays if `currentMode == 'Text'`; else, show `'bgImage'`.

I want to stop or destory `'bgImage'` when `this.imageShape` equals `'textImage'` because when `'textImage'` came, it overlapped on `'bgImage'`.

Comment: The `else` condition won't run if the `if` condition is true. Are you already loading `'bgImage'` prior to this? If so, we might need to see that logic.

Comment: actually i want to fix textImage on screen
i just want to change when 'currentMode' equals to 'Backgrounnd' it have to show bgImage